# Evitar cambiar fuente en dispositivos móviles

Tags: jquery, html, css

Tengo un problema con la fuente que estoy utilizando para mi diseño (una mono-space que viene por defecto); pero cuando lo abro desde teléfono (en concreto desde iPhone) ésta cambia automáticamente, ¿hay alguna forma de cambiar esto?

Así es como uso la fuente en mi proyecto:

```css
.font{
    font-family:Consolas, "Andale Mono", "Lucida Console", "Lucida Sans Typewriter", Monaco, "Courier New", monospace;
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué fuente es? ¿Cómo se agrega al proyecto? ¿Cómo se usa dentro del proyecto?

Comment: Hola @AlvaroMontoro es una Andale Mono que en el iphone me cambia a Helvetica la solución que he improvisado por el momento es prever el cambio de fuente y ajustar el diseño a éste.

Comment: ¿Cómo la incluyes en el proyecto?¿y como indicas en CSS que debe usarla para algún elemento?

Comment: Mediante  "font-family:" y funciona como esperaba hasta que introduzco la url en el teléfono.

Comment: ¿Usas @font-face para incluirla en el proyecto?

Comment: He realizado una edición para que veas cómo la introduzco

Comment: Pero no incluyes "Andale Mono" en tu proyecto usando @font-face, ¿verdad?

Comment: No @AlvaroMontoro , esto es lo único que aplico. De todos modos, encontré una solución que me satisface ya al prever el cambio de fuente ajustando a helvética el contenido.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que no estás incluyendo la fuente en tu proyecto, por eso te funciona en el ordenador pero no en el teléfono. El problema con el siguiente código:

```
.font{
    font-family:Consolas, "Andale Mono", "Lucida Console", "Lucida Sans Typewriter", Monaco, "Courier New", monospace;
}
```

es que tu navegador busca las fuentes indicadas, bien porque las enlazas dentro de tu proyecto (cosa que no haces) o bien porque ya las tienes instaladas en tu ordenador (que es el caso). Como la tienes en tu ordenador, la ves bien; pero como no la tienes en tu teléfono móvil (**y tus usuarios puede que no la tengan en su ordenador tampoco**) verás la primera fuente válida.

Para solucionar esto, añade la fuente usando [`@font-face`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face), que puedes aplicar así:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: <nombre-de-fuente-remota>;
  src: <origen> [,<origen>]*;
  [font-weight: <peso>];
  [font-style: <estilo>];
}
```

En tu caso sería:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Andale Mono";
  src: url( <ruta-donde-tengas-la-fuente-online> );
}
```

Comment: Entiendo, como a mi me salía por defecto no entendía que quizás a otros no. Muchas gracias :)

Comment: Te recomendaría que la incluyeras en el proyecto, así todos los usuarios tendrán una misma experiencia, en lugar de algunos usuarios ver la página con una fuente y otros usuarios verla con otra fuente diferente

Comment: Precisamente estoy haciéndolo ahora, cada día aprendo cosas nuevas